# How to parse Json and used nested loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 sets of JSON data but I'm not sure how to use javascript and parse the information.
API1, data stored in variable called response1:

```
[{"placeid":1,"place_name":"arora-square","city":"miami","state":"florida","country":"US"},   {"placeid":2,"place_name":"hoover","city":"palo-alto","state":"california","country":"US"}
```

API2, data stored in variable called response2:

```
[  
   {  
      "manufacturer":"apple",
      "market_name":"apple_market1",
      "codename":"xx",
      "model":"iphone",
      "usage_statistics":{  
         "session_infos":[  
            {  
               "building_id":17,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":9,
                     "item_category_id":9,
                     "cost":100
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":81,
                     "item_category_id":6,
                     "cost":300
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":197,
                     "item_category_id":2,
                     "cost":4
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "building_id":18,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":94,
                     "item_category_id":4,
                     "cost":150
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":126,
                     "item_category_id":6,
                     "cost":400
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":180,
                     "item_category_id":0,
                     "cost":300
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "building_id":16,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":78,
                     "item_category_id":3,
                     "cost":30
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":30,
                     "item_category_id":0,
                     "cost":101.77
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":103,
                     "item_category_id":13,
                     "cost":52.92
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":25,
                     "item_category_id":10,
                     "cost":106.87
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":161,
                     "item_category_id":11,
                     "cost":145.23
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":70,
                     "item_category_id":10,
                     "cost":19.32
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":113,
                     "item_category_id":8,
                     "cost":136.96
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":43,
                     "item_category_id":13,
                     "cost":115.86
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":59,
                     "item_category_id":14,
                     "cost":114.13
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":171,
                     "item_category_id":6,
                     "cost":46.61
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "building_id":16,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":39,
                     "item_category_id":9,
                     "cost":128.04
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":167,
                     "item_category_id":2,
                     "cost":65.36
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":190,
                     "item_category_id":10,
                     "cost":79.08
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":83,
                     "item_category_id":8,
                     "cost":116.38
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":153,
                     "item_category_id":3,
                     "cost":125.87
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":43,
                     "item_category_id":13,
                     "cost":115.86
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":114,
                     "item_category_id":9,
                     "cost":112.14
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":31,
                     "item_category_id":1,
                     "cost":136.3
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":8,
                     "item_category_id":8,
                     "cost":110.61
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":4,
                     "item_category_id":4,
                     "cost":80.13
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "building_id":17,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":117,
                     "item_category_id":12,
                     "cost":138.33
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":3,
                     "item_category_id":3,
                     "cost":82.21
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":6,
                     "item_category_id":6,
                     "cost":51.55
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":139,
                     "item_category_id":4,
                     "cost":132.47
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {  
      "manufacturer":"Samsung",
      "market_name":"Galaxy S7 Edge",
      "codename":"hero2lte",
      "model":"SM-G935F",
      "usage_statistics":{  
         "session_infos":[  
            {  
               "building_id":17,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":137,
                     "item_category_id":2,
                     "cost":112.87
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":53,
                     "item_category_id":8,
                     "cost":140.45
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":21,
                     "item_category_id":6,
                     "cost":126.53
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":177,
                     "item_category_id":12,
                     "cost":130.49
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":41,
                     "item_category_id":11,
                     "cost":48.16
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":130,
                     "item_category_id":10,
                     "cost":114.39
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":66,
                     "item_category_id":6,
                     "cost":90.03
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":192,
                     "item_category_id":12,
                     "cost":74.78
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":27,
                     "item_category_id":12,
                     "cost":131.27
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":182,
                     "item_category_id":2,
                     "cost":23.37
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "building_id":18,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":82,
                     "item_category_id":7,
                     "cost":127.05
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":143,
                     "item_category_id":8,
                     "cost":106.03
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":86,
                     "item_category_id":11,
                     "cost":89.86
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "building_id":18,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":57,
                     "item_category_id":12,
                     "cost":112.88
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":10,
                     "item_category_id":10,
                     "cost":143.22
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":171,
                     "item_category_id":6,
                     "cost":46.61
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":136,
                     "item_category_id":1,
                     "cost":74.89
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":115,
                     "item_category_id":10,
                     "cost":134.47
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":160,
                     "item_category_id":10,
                     "cost":109.55
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":70,
                     "item_category_id":10,
                     "cost":19.32
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":26,
                     "item_category_id":11,
                     "cost":28.86
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":8,
                     "item_category_id":8,
                     "cost":110.61
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":43,
                     "item_category_id":13,
                     "cost":115.86
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "building_id":17,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":102,
                     "item_category_id":12,
                     "cost":117.67
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":136,
                     "item_category_id":1,
                     "cost":74.89
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":167,
                     "item_category_id":2,
                     "cost":65.36
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":173,
                     "item_category_id":8,
                     "cost":143.73
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":125,
                     "item_category_id":5,
                     "cost":113.33
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":140,
                     "item_category_id":5,
                     "cost":30.33
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "building_id":16,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":149,
                     "item_category_id":14,
                     "cost":106.59
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":152,
                     "item_category_id":2,
                     "cost":123.09
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":87,
                     "item_category_id":12,
                     "cost":1.46
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":49,
                     "item_category_id":4,
                     "cost":50.82
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":86,
                     "item_category_id":11,
                     "cost":89.86
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":48,
                     "item_category_id":3,
                     "cost":103.54
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":10,
                     "item_category_id":10,
                     "cost":143.22
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":162,
                     "item_category_id":12,
                     "cost":21.48
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":11,
                     "item_category_id":11,
                     "cost":70.23
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":118,
                     "item_category_id":13,
                     "cost":19.45
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "building_id":16,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":20,
                     "item_category_id":5,
                     "cost":133.59
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":82,
                     "item_category_id":7,
                     "cost":127.05
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":111,
                     "item_category_id":6,
                     "cost":60.91
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "building_id":17,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":22,
                     "item_category_id":7,
                     "cost":56.14
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":91,
                     "item_category_id":1,
                     "cost":22.52
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":149,
                     "item_category_id":14,
                     "cost":106.59
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "building_id":18,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":168,
                     "item_category_id":3,
                     "cost":54.33
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":22,
                     "item_category_id":7,
                     "cost":56.14
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "building_id":17,
               "purchases":[  
                  {  
                     "item_id":79,
                     "item_category_id":4,
                     "cost":53.53
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":60,
                     "item_category_id":0,
                     "cost":117.82
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":72,
                     "item_category_id":12,
                     "cost":148.69
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":107,
                     "item_category_id":2,
                     "cost":48.71
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":18,
                     "item_category_id":3,
                     "cost":142.67
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":145,
                     "item_category_id":10,
                     "cost":127.1
                  },
                  {  
                     "item_id":139,
                     "item_category_id":4,
                     "cost":132.47
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

need to figure out for example : total cost in the country( US) and which building ( name or id) has most total cost.

Comment: `JSON.parse()`...

Comment: If you're completely clueless, I'd suggest looking up a JavaScript tutorial and starting from there. Otherwise, an attempt from you to work off of would be nice.

Comment: share your complete json

Comment: @sumit complete json is over 10000 lines , i just posted sample. Can u help me get total cost of people in the US for example, just need to see an example

Comment: at least post minimal sample json rather than etc... so that we can help you

Comment: @sumit updated post

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd do is [beautify](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) that ugly JSON to a more human-friendly form, obtaining something like this:

```
[
  {
    "placeid": 1,
    "place_name": "arora-square",
    "city": "miami",
    "state": "florida",
    "country": "US"
  },
  {
    "placeid": 2,
    "place_name": "hoover",
    "city": "palo-alto",
    "state": "california",
    "country": "US"
  }
]
```

Once you're done with that, just remember that `{}` surrounds an object, while `[]` represents a list. In the first case, to access a specific property just use `object.property`, while in the second one you can access the i-th element using `list[index]`.

For example, if you have `o = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}`, you can easily retrieve `value1` using `v1 = o.key1`.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `JSON.parse()`, your `JSON` is basically an object and can be directly accessed from the array using the `foreach` method

```js
var response2 = [{"placeid":1,"place_name":"arora-square","city":"miami","state":"florida","country":"US"},   {"placeid":2,"place_name":"hoover","city":"palo-alto","state":"california","country":"US"}]

response2.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.placeid);
  console.log(element.place_name);
  console.log(element.city);
  console.log(element.state);
  console.log("---");
});
```

To use `JSON.parse()`, you need to convent your `JSON` into a string and then assign it to the array. After that, use `foreach` method to simply loop through the array content and parse each `JSON` content.

```js
var response1 = ["{\"placeid\":\"1\",\"place_name\":\"arora-square\",\"city\":\"miami\",\"state\":\"florida\",\"country\":\"US\"}", "{\"placeid\": \"2\",\"place_name\":\"hoover\",\"city\":\"palo-alto\",\"state\":\"california\",\"country\":\"US\"}"];

response1.forEach(function(element) {
  element = JSON.parse(element);
  console.log(element.placeid);
  console.log(element.place_name);
  console.log(element.city);
  console.log(element.state);
  console.log("---");
});
```

The second method will be applicable in cases like `AJAX` calls, where you are receiving back `JSON` encoded data.

Comment: so how would I calculate the total cost in the US and print that to html, not just console,log

Comment: What do you mean by total cost? Which properties do you want to sum up?

Comment: so in API2 u see all the costs, i need to sum all those up that are in the same country, SO i can do that by looking at API1, all objects with country US and then  use buildingID since that's the only similar thing in api2, then add all cost up with those matching